# How can I create temp table many times in plpgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to create temp table many times.
I do that in a function of plpgsql.
But if I do so, error happens like below.

> ERROR:  out of shared memory HINT:  You might need to increase
> max_locks_per_transaction.

And I tried not to create but reuse table with truncate table and insert to table.
But I can't insert to table in plpgsql.

How can I handle that?

Comment: "*I would like to create temp table many times*" this sounds like the wrong approach. You can definitely insert into a temp table in PL/pgSQ, even multiple times. Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete code of your stored function (or procedure) to your question. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: thank you for your comment. Now I can do what I want to do. Point is do not use into statement to store values, but use insert into a temp table as you told! thankyou!